# Find the real parameter a so that the equation has real and positive roots

Tags: quadratics

My problem is:

$(2-x)(x+1)=a$

How do I find the value of the parameter $a$ so that the equation has real and positive roots?

Comment: Velcome to the site!  You should try to tell us what did you try!

Answer (score 3):

Your equation can be written

$$x^2-x+(a-2)=0$$

This is a [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation), and it has real roots if it's [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant) $\Delta$ is $\geq0$, with $\Delta = 1-4\cdot(a-2)=9-4a$, so you need $a\leq 9/4=2{,}25$.

Then the roots are positive if both the sum of the roots and their product are positive. The sum is always $1$, from [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Vieta.27s_formulas)), and the product of the root is $a-2$, so you need $a>2$.

So, the condition is $2<a\leq 2{,}25$.